# 1 of my DLLs is not compiling correctly when on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, build

When compiled locally everything works correctly no matter if i use the debug, release or our custom azure build configuration. Solution has 29 projects every other DLL seems to be working correctly.

When checked in to azure it builds deploys and does not work. 
I have added extra logging into the code which appears to never be hit. 
After de-compiling the problematic DLL I can see that its not correct and does not have my extra logging.

Currently I have to manually upload just one DLL the rest of the DLLs are all fine

I am not sure what process I need to go through to figure out why this DLL is not being built correctly

Comment: We're going to need just a bit more info... Please check the build configuration and make sure the 'missing' DLL is in there and checked. Also, check the bitness of the assemblies and the resource where it needs to land in Azure.

Comment: There is no missing DLL 
Azure deploys a DLL just when the DLL is de-complied it does not appear to be the same as there is missing logging

Comment: It's probably somewhere in the build configuration, but we can't say for certain unless you provide us with more information. We need for example the build configuration, the build template, how the solution is set up, etc.